# Make simple bitmap feel like real Mondrian painting

Tags: color, overlay

I'm using a bitmap API with Java in an effort to make a Mondrian-esque painting.

This is my result:

[image]

This is what i want to achive:

[image]

How can I try to make the image I generated more like a Mondrian painting? I imagine an overlay and off colors would help? Is there anything else?

Comment: What I see is a poor photograph of a Mondrian. The ones I have seen in person are fairly neutral, bright whites. So are you asking how to make it look more "analog and poorly lit as if taken with a high ISO grainy photo"? Also: are you able to do the standard copy, merge, stretch blt with transparency or alpha?

Answer (score 3):

The black lines should have some variation in thickness. Eliminate the line around the outside as it breaks the flow of the grid outside the frame, which Mondrian was playing with. Notice that in the painting each colored block could go on outside the frame and we are only seeing a cropped piece of something larger or perhaps infinite. pay close attention to the range of sizes of blocks and how the sizes are distributed. This fine tuning could make a big difference in achieving the "look" of Mondrian.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like:

```
#e7eccc (R: 231, G: 236, B: 204) instead of white,
#8c1f00 (R: 140, G: 31, B: 0) instead of red,
#0c183e (R: 12, G: 24, B: 62) instead of blue,
#d29b00 (R: 210, G: 155, B: 0) instead of yellow,
#11120c (R: 17, G: 18, B: 12) instead of black
```

If it still doesn't feel right, try randomly filling the rectangles with dots slightly darker then the color, creating some noise, or apply a pattern, previously created in Photoshop or even Paint instead of the color fill.

I don't know the possibilities of the bitmap API, but if you can use layers, then I would apply some transparent layers with some semi-transparent grey slightly artistic brush strokes, but it involves using Photoshop.

Comment: do you know a good resource for already done (or some tutorial for doing it) some "semi-transparent grey slightly artistic brush strokes" ?

Comment: @nkint - why ask where you can find a tutorial? Why not just ask for more detail? I am curious...

Comment: because i think that if i asking for tutorial is more general then details. of course details could be more appropriate. i have searched a bit on google but photoshop is not my software : ) do you have any hints?

Comment: I think that no brushes are needed, just add noise, like it is shown here : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/how-do-i-get-this-uneven-airbrush-effect-similar-to-old-art-deco-posters , as Skaught pointed out.