# How to create grungy shadows in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to produce the grungy shadows on the girl's face in the illustration below. Is it just a matter of finding the right brush and fine-tuning, or is there an easier process?

[image: Guts Gig Poster by Jake Sauer]

<sub>Source: Guts Gig Poster by Jake Sauer</sub>

Comment: It's most likely a grunge brush with fine tuning as you mentioned. Not everything has an automated feature in the Adobe suite.

Comment: Right, I figured. The reason I'm unsure is because the shadows have a fairly uniform quality (vertically-oriented, grungy). Does seem likely that it's a grunge brush that's painted on, and maybe the same grunge brush used to erase.

Comment: That is a halftone effect. It's meant to mimic the printing process. Here's a tutorial that illustrates one of the ways you can achieve a similar effect http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXaMpsZIk9Y

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get this uneven airbrush effect similar to old art deco posters?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/how-do-i-get-this-uneven-airbrush-effect-similar-to-old-art-deco-posters)

Answer (score 3):

I am sure it is not a brush, the grungy shadow effect was created by a texture applied on Overlay or Soft Light blending mode.
What makes me sure about it is the fact that the shadows doesn't look all the same, and are also in the grey area.

Here are some examples of textures you could use:

http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs16/f/2007/158/c/f/Grunge_by_darkrose42_stock.jpg

http://versporttvonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Shadowhouse-creations-b-w-grunge-texture-set.jpg

http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs50/i/2009/334/0/0/Grunge_Texture_Stock_by_XactoInTheBox.jpg

http://gutturaldeath.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/grungetexture-4.jpg

http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/313/1/2/grunge_texture_overlay_2_by_cesstrelle-d5khe3g.jpg

Do the following:

- Apply a texture of your choice over the image and blend it in Overlay or Soft Light mode;
- If it gets too dark or too light, use an adjustment layer [image: In case you wonder whre the adjustment layers are] and make it only visible by the texture layer by clicking [image] in the adjustment layer panel.
- If you want to have the effect only on a certain part of your artwork, simply erase with a soft brush in the areas where the effect shouldn't be.

Really hope it helps.

Comment: "simply erase" **or** "add a layer mask and paint on the mask to add/remove non-destructively"

Comment: @horatio thanks for the sum, I thought about it. Forgot writing down.