# How create such amazingly smooth grain with gradient like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

[image]

Is it made in Photoshop or illustrator? I tried many way but can't reach this smooth level

Comment: Hi ian, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: It's either a scanned texture or simply the noise filter.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/how-do-i-get-this-uneven-airbrush-effect-similar-to-old-art-deco-posters/9486#9486

Answer (score 0):

Going along with the comments, if you want to design the noise yourself in Photoshop, you can do the following:

1) Make an object with the pen tool and fill with some color. You can use Yellow like the picture if you want.

2) Make a new layer - fill with black.

3) Filter -> Noise -> Add Noise (I used 17.55%, Uniform, Monochromatic. Mess around with the options)

4) Apply a layer mask between the 2 layers (so the black is clipped by the object)

5) Apply a screen layer effect to the noise layer

5) If you want the noise more prominent select the noise layer and go to Layer -> Adjustments -> Brightness. You can also scale the noise to make the particles larger.

Comment: A slightly more elegant way to do this is to use gradients. That's the way to do it in Illustrator as well. Mind if I edit and add to your answer a bit?

Comment: You may edit and add to my answer.