# How to achieve graphite texture in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have a rather specific question. I drew a little design of a radio tower on paper with a graphite pencil. I have become obsessed with replicating the exact texture that my pencil produced. The image below is a zoomed-in look at the design.

Is there a way to achieve that texture/look?

Thank you in advance! :)

[image: Close-up of the design]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/how-do-i-get-this-uneven-airbrush-effect-similar-to-old-art-deco-posters

Comment: There are some pretty good brushes out there in the world wide web... like this one for instance: https://creativemarket.com/DaniMadBrushes/1176131-The-Sketcher-Collection-Brushes

Comment: Thank you both very much for the responses! Helped me out a lot!