# How could I achieve the following styles using adobe photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, style-identification, noise

Very very grateful for any suggestions to the following:

As asked above, how could I achieve the following style using adobe photoshop?

The first:

[image]

And the second:

[image]

Comment: Possibly Helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/how-do-i-get-this-uneven-airbrush-effect-similar-to-old-art-deco-posters Your specific samples merely look like the Noise filter was used heavily.

Comment: Thank you very much - that's very helpful!